# Superset with Apache Spark on Hive

Tags: apache-spark-sql, hive, apache-superset

I have Apache Superset installed via Docker on my local machine. I have a separate production 20 Node Spark cluster with Hive as the Meta-Store. I want my SuperSet to be able to connect to Hive and run queries via Spark-SQL.
For connecting to Hive, I tried the following

**Add Database --> SQLAlchemy URI ***

`hive://hive@<hostname>:10000/default`

but it is giving some error when I test connection. I believe I have to do some tunneling, but I am not sure how.

I have the Hive thrift server as well.

Please let me know how to proceed.

Comment: Is it an extremely long error that covers the whole page with "root cannot execute as user hive" or similar somewhere in there? If yes, you need to set hive.server2.enable.doAs=false

Answer (score 0):

What is the error you are receiving? Although the docs do not mention this, the best way to provide the connection URL is in the following format :

```
hive://<url>/default?auth=NONE    ( when there is no security )
hive://<url>/default?auth=KERBEROS
hive://<url>/default?auth=LDAP
```

Answer (score 0):

- first you should connect the 2 containers together.
- lets say you have the container_superset that runs superset and container_spark running spark.
- run : `docker network  ls` # display containers and its network
- select the name of the superset network (should be something like superset_default )
- run : `docker run --network="superset_default" --name=NameTheConatinerHere  --publish port1:port2 imageName`
  ---> port1:port2 is the port mapping and imageName is the image of spak